# php xdebug wamp automatically create profile file

Tags: php, debugging, profile, xdebug

This thing is driving me crazy. I'm using xdebug on WAMP and I can't get it to automatically generate profile files...
Here's my php.ini code:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.10/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\wamp\tmp\xdebug"

xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir="C:\wamp\tmp\xdebug"
xdebug.collect_params=1
xdebug.collect_return=1
```

I've tried about every .ini configuration you could imagine though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL I was editing the wrong php.ini file. Sorry guys, it happens.